# Laravel loop through query result, then paginate

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm working on an event booking system. When the user searches for a date range, I use a function inside my `Event` model that checks if the event is available. My search function currently works as follows:

```
    $events = Event::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('term') . '%')
        ->where('accepted',1)
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->get('term').'%')
        ->orWhere('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->get('term').'%')->paginate(15);

    $availableEvents = new Collection();

    if ($request->get('from') !== '' AND $request->get('to') !== '') {
        foreach($events as $key => $event) {
            if ($event->is_available($request->get('from'), $request->get('to'))) {
                $availableEvents->add($event);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $availableEvents = $events;
    }

    return view('frontend.events.results', ['events' => $availableEvents, 'request' => $request]);
```

I can't check availability inside the query builder so I have to loop through. I'm using a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` because I can't remove events from the paginated thing I get from the query builder.

Is there some way to convert the Eloquent Collection to a paginated collection?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm passing `$request` to the view to use `appends()` so I can retain the query string parameters during pagination.

EDIT: The `is_available` function

```
public function is_available($from, $to) {

    $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $from);
    $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $to);

    foreach($this->not_availables as $notAvailable) {

        $notAvailableFrom = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $notAvailable->from);
        $notAvailableTo = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $notAvailable->to);

        if ($from->gte($notAvailableFrom) OR $to->lte($notAvailableTo)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `->whereBetween('event_date', [$from, $to])` in your query builder? We can't see what your `is_available($from, $to)` function does, but I'm assuming you manually check it.

Comment: @Ciccio Unfortunately not. We save the periods when events are not available in a separate table. This table contains the id of the event and a from and to date of the unavailability. Method has been added to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually create a [paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

You could use `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` like this:

```
use \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

...

$page = $request->get('page', 1);
$limit = 10;
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $availableEvents->forPage($page, $limit), $availableEvents->count(), $limit, $page, ['path' => $request->path()]
);
```

Then pass the `$paginator` along with your view, instead of your `$availableEvents`. In your view you still have `$events`, you can render the pagination with `$events->render();` and pass on the route parameters from `$request` as you normally would.